# Every subset of a well-ordered set is identical to a union of intervals of the set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

"Every subset of a well-ordered set is identical to a union of intervals of the set"

I was wondering whether the statement has a name and whether it needs to be restricted to be true.

Comment: What is your definition of "interval"? Is every one-element set an interval, because $\{a\}=[a,a]$?

Comment: Yes actually, I guess that makes it trivially true.